# Callback not executed in Android unit test with injected mock object

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, dagger-2, robolectric

I am new to unit testing in Android and have gone through several tutorials to get myself familiar with mockito and robolectric.

My app is using Dagger 2 to inject my `EventService` into my `MainActivity`. For my `MainActivityUnitTest`, I have set up a `TestServicesModule` to provide a mocked version of `EventService` so that I can use Robolectric to run unit tests against my `MainActivity`

I'm having an issue getting the `ServiceCallback` on my `EventService.getAllEvents(callback: ServiceCallback)` to execute in the unit test. I have verified in the `@Setup` of my `MainActivityUnitTest` class that the `EventService` is being injected as a mocked object. I have gone through several tutorials and blog posts and as far as I can tell, I am doing everything correctly. The `refreshData()` function in `MainActivity` is getting called successfully, and I can see that the call to `eventsService.getAllEvents(callback)` is being executed. But the `doAnswer {}` lambda function is never getting executed.

Here's my relevant code:

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AppModule::class,
    ServicesModule::class,
    FirebaseModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(target: MainActivity)
}
```

ServicesModule.kt

```
@Module
open class ServicesModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    open fun provideEventService(db: FirebaseFirestore): EventsService {
        return EventsServiceImpl(db)
    }
}
```

EventsService.kt

```
interface EventsService {
    fun getAllEvents(callback: ServiceCallback<List<Event>>)
    fun getEvent(id: String, callback: ServiceCallback<Event?>)
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject lateinit var eventsService: EventsService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        (application as App).appComponent.inject(this)
        ...
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        refreshData()
    }

    eventsService.getAllEvents(object: ServiceCallback<List<Event>> {
        override fun onCompletion(result: List<Event>) {
            viewModel.allEvents.value = result
            loading_progress.hide()
        }
    })
}
```

Now we get into the tests:

TestAppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    TestServicesModule::class
])
interface TestAppComponent : AppComponent {
    fun inject(target: MainActivityUnitTest)
}
```

TestServicesModule.kt

```
@Module
class TestServicesModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideEventsService(): EventsService {
        return mock()
    }
}
```

MainActivityUnitTest.kt

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(application = TestApp::class)
class MainActivityUnitTest {

    @Inject lateinit var eventsService: EventsService

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        val testComponent = DaggerTestAppComponent.builder().build()
        testComponent.inject(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun givenActivityStarted_whenLoadFailed_shouldDisplayNoEventsMessage() {
        val events = ArrayList<Event>()

        doAnswer {
            //this block is never hit during debug
            val callback: ServiceCallback<List<Event>> = it.getArgument(0)
            callback.onCompletion(events)
        }.whenever(eventsService).getAllEvents(any())

        val activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity::class.java).create().start().visible().get()
        val noEventsView = activity.findViewById(R.id.no_events) as View

        //this always evaluates to null because the callback is never set from the doAnswer lambda
        assertThat(callback).isNotNull()
        verify(callback)!!.onCompletion(events)
        assertThat(noEventsView.visibility).isEqualTo(View.VISIBLE)
    }
}
```

**Edit: Adding App and TestApp**

```
open class App : Application() {
    private val TAG = this::class.qualifiedName
    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = initDagger(this)
    }

    open fun initDagger(app: App): AppComponent {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(AppModule(app)).build()
    }
}

class TestApp : App() {
    override fun initDagger(app: App): AppComponent {
        return DaggerTestAppComponent.builder().build()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a different component to inject your test and activity. As they're different components I suspect you are using 2 different instances of the eventsService.

Your test uses a local DaggerTestAppComponent.

```
@Inject lateinit var eventsService: EventsService

@Before
fun setup() {
    val testComponent = DaggerTestAppComponent.builder().build()
    testComponent.inject(this)
}
```

While your Activity uses the appComponent from the application.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject lateinit var eventsService: EventsService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        (application as App).appComponent.inject(this)
        ...
    }
```

To overcome this you may consider adding a test version of your application class, this would allow you to replace the AppComponent in your application with your TestAppComponent. Robolectric should allow you to create a test application as follows: http://robolectric.org/custom-test-runner/

Comment: So I have a TestApp class that extends my App class, which overrides Dagger for the test suite. My understanding is that this was the purpose? So that the TestAppComponent would override the dependencies provided by the AppComponent for Activity dependencies? I'll add relevant code to the question above.

Comment: Also, when I place a breakpoint on the call in the activity while debugging the test, it reports that eventService is an instance of `EventsService$MockitoMock`

Comment: Your TestApp is setup if you're seeing a mock in the activity. You just need to use the same component to inject your test in order to use the same eventsService.  Instead of creating a new component in your test you can use the component setup in your TestApp. I think with robolectric you can access this through RuntimeEnvironment.application - this should be of type TestApp which will allow you to access the appComponent for injection.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. Thanks!